# If eating 100% fat 2 times more worth the energy I spend during the day, will I store body fat?

Tags: liver, fat-metabolism, insulin

So in theory, insulin hormone is the one that tells the body "eat more. don't burn body fat". Alongside with glucose blood level regulation and turning excessive glucose into liver (which later goes into muscles as glycogen or into fat cells). Fats are the only thing that do not provoke insulin secretion. 0 glycemic index.

So in theory, if I eat 2 or 3 times more worth the energy I spend during the day, I'll never store body fat because of 0 glycemic index?

Or will I still gain because such huge fat intake will make liver into making glucose from fats & proteins?

Surely u'll never find a sustainable product to eat that is 100% fat, but just a few examples are butter, lard, heavy cream. This is just a theoretical question, where the proteins/carbs intake is so low that it is not count.

Could you please clarify it since I got lost.

Comment: Interesting question! I would guess adipose fatty uptake and esterification would increase with higher fat ingestion, regardless of insulin levels, simply because there is more fat around. The body cannot make glucose from fat, so fat accumulation via glucose is not a possible. (Which is also a reason why such a diet would be lethal.)

Comment: @Roland how come it can't? It can. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluconeogenesis

Comment: @Roland and also I can't consider "simply because there is more fat around" a legit argument. I am really curious about this and my local dietitians can't seem to satisfy my interest. Something has to tell the body to start storing the fat. If it's not insulin (that is significantly elevats due to carbs/protein intake), then what else can tell the body to store the fat? Btw what about "lethality" of this diet. I eat about 80% fat and 10% protein from calories. Other - from leafy greens. Also intake a lot of fiber and electrolytes. Not dead yet. Even more. I cycle 60k+ day at high speeds.

Comment: Gluconeogensis from fat doesn't work due to stoichiometric problems. With only acetyl-CoA from fatty acids, the TCA cycle cannot function, because oxaloacetate used for gluconeogenesis cannot be replenished. Organisms that can turn fat to sugar use something called the glyoxylate cycle, which doesn't exist in humans. See any major biochemistry textbook, like Stryer's.

Comment: I meant that there is likely a basal rate of fat uptake by adipose tissue even if you don't get a glucose-induced insulin peak. And adipose fat storage probably is faster at higher plasma fatty acid levels (I'm guessing). Also, note that in the presence of glucose, fatty acids do increase plasma insulin (see for example http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15929861), and animals and people on high fat diets are known to have higher insulin.

Comment: As for "lethality". 80% energy from fat (which sounds like a lot to me) corresponds to 65% fat in your diet (by weight). So you are still taking in 35% carbs and protein. Your hypothetical 100% fat diet would be more like drinking oil and eating nothing else.

Comment: "is the one that tells the body" sounds like a strange way to say it. The response to food is regulated by many more hormones and neurotransmitters. For example, gut cells secrete GLP-1 in response to both fat and carbohydrates. I don't know all pathways involved but I'd be very surprised if insulin is the only mechanism involved in telling the body to store fat. And then there is the theory that the trouble behind metabolic disorders doesn't come from storing too much fat, but  from storing too little fat - the overconsumed but unstored fat would wreak havoc in different tissues.

Comment: Agree with @Roland - any basic biochemistry textbook (i.e. Stryer) will tell you that you can't make sugar from fat. That is, you can't make glucose from fatty acids because the reaction catalyzed by pyruvate dehydrogenase is irreversible. When someone goes on a high fat diet (i.e. Atkins diet), they force themselves to become ketotic - which means the body begins making a significant amount of ketone bodies from the breakdown of fatty acids. The body is trying to 'hold on' to its glucose reserves by burning ketone bodies, which can cross the blood brain barrier for brain energy metabolism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this approach doesn't work quite as well as you might hope.

First, insulin doesn't go away after a high-fat meal. [This paper](http://www.jissn.com/content/8/1/19) reports changes in serum insulin following pure-sugar and pure-fat meals. Although there is much less of an increase in insulin following the pure-fat versus the pure-sugar meal, you will notice in Figure 1 that the insulin levels following the pure-fat meals (panel A) are higher than the levels during a fast (panel B). So even if high insulin were the only signal for fat storage, your dream of eliminating insulin with a high-fat meal is not realistic.

Second, when a high-fat diet is designed for [medical purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketogenic_diet), a good deal of care is required to avoid significant potential adverse effects. Adequate protein intake is still required, and amino acids from the protein can be converted to glucose. Furthermore, ketoacids are produced when fatty acids from ingested fat are in excess. (As noted in comments, humans do not convert fatty acids to glucose.) Although ketoacids can be excreted in the urine (admittedly, heading toward your goal of not storing all the calories you consume), the net metabolic effect on the body when you excrete ketoacids is increased acidification, which in turn can lead to difficulties with potassium regulation and thus, in severe cases, with heart function. In the extreme if this were continued for a long time, you may face a problem of life-threatening [ketoacidosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketoacidosis) as occurs in type-1 diabetics (low/no insulin) whose disease is not being managed.

That said, your basic idea is similar to the arguments for [low-carbohydrate diets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-carbohydrate_diet). How well they work and, if they do, through what mechanisms are still somewhat controversial, as I understand. Insofar as they work through excreting some of the ingested fat through urinary loss of ketoacids, however, the associated risks need to be considered.